# Can't override Express Request User type, but I can add new properties to Request

Tags: typescript, express

This is a typical issue with what seems like a common solution. The Express Request object has a property named user which is typed as Express.User (an empty object).

I try the common solution used to retype it:

```js
// index.d.ts

import { User as PrismaUser, Profile } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      user: PrismaUser & { profile: Profile };
    }
  }
}
```

That file is captured by my `tsconfig.json` file.

When I do the above, I get the following error:

> All declarations of 'user' must have identical modifiers.ts(2687)
>
> Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property
> 'user' must be of type 'User', but here has type 'User & { profile:
> Profile; }'.

Essentially, I'm being told that it has to be typed as Express.User.

Meanwhile, the following works:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      currentUser: PrismaUser & { profile: Profile };
    }
  }
}
```

I could then use `request.currentUser` in my code.

Why can't I change the type of the user property though like so many other answers I see given here? I don't see anyone else running into my error. Perhaps my tsconfig is broken?

Comment: `PrismaUser & { profile?: Profile }` Does this work for you? Essentially the error is telling you that you can't add non optional properties to an existing declaration.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is a really odd issue. The error is basically saying this can only be a Express.User type... but doesn't that go completely against declaration merging?

Comment: Well... I guess the issue makes sense. It is because the @types/passport is giving a type of Express.User...

Answer (score 8):

I was going about this all wrong.

@types/passport added an Express.User to Express and made Express.Request.User the Express.User type...

What I had to do was the following

```js
import { User, Profile } from "@prisma/client";

type ProductUser = User & { profile: Profile };

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User extends ProductUser {}
  }
}
```

That avoids trying to use declaration merging for a property that is already merged, which gives me the error I experienced.